# Change URL params or remove some part of URL with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I have this URL and wanting to know how can I remove this section from it via a jQuery event.

Need to remove:

&activities_id=13&session_id=14&back=1

Original URL:

http://somedomain.com/ijob-css/index.php/search/default/index/area/act?query=&activities_id=13&session_id=14&back=1

EDIT

Sorry i think i havent included the most important section. I should change the Address BAR url not a normal string.

for example, if i have this url in the address bar - http://somedomain.com/ijob-css/index.php/ after  change, address bar should contain http://somedomain.com/xxx=111, without page refreshing.

Comment: You could remove this from a string which was assigned the URI but is that what you want? Or do you want to actually point the browser to a new URI minus the parts you want to remove?

Comment: @andrew-buchan i want to remove the mentioned section from the URL and leave the page without refreshing.  its like this, once user presses aback button he is taken here to a show a preloaded dialog box. so after showing the dialog box i need to remove that portion from URL without page is being reloaded.

Comment: Check out the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history) from my answer below. I believe replaceState() is the answer for your problem. However it is not supported in all browsers/versions. History.js wraps HTML5 state features and provides additional support for HTML4 browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want the URL without the query parameter part? If then see if this helps.

```
var test = 'http://somedomain.com/ijob-css/index.php/search/default/index/area/act?query=&activities_id=13&session_id=14&back=1';

alert(test.substring(0, test.indexOf('?')));
```

If you want until first query parameter name then just seek until index of &

**Update :**

If you are using HTML5 then what you ask is possible. Check browser history manipulation. You can find details about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

I believe replaceState() is the answer for your problem. However it is not supported in all browsers/versions. History.js wraps HTML5 state features and provides additional support for HTML4 browsers.

Comment: Yes. This is doable. Check [this](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/) link out. It explains the steps in detail. Also check out the example link in that page. It changes the URL everytime to fetch a photo without page reload.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out**

```
var new_url = old_url.substring(0, old_url.indexOf('&'));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SjrqF/

```
var url = 'youtube.com/watch?v=3sZOD3xKL0Y&feature=youtube_gdata';

url = url.slice( 0, url.indexOf('&') );
```

or:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SjrqF/1/

```
var url = 'youtube.com/watch?v=3sZOD3xKL0Y&feature=youtube_gdata';

url = url.split( '&' )[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastPart = 'query=';
var url = 'http://somedomain.com/ijob-css/index.php/search/default/index/area/act?query=&activities_id=13&session_id=14&back=1'.split(lastPart)[0] + lastPart;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = original_url.indexOf("=");
var new_url = original_url.substring(0,index+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

See below.

```
var positionToSubstring = this.location.href.indexOf('&');
var newURI = this.location.href.substring(0, positionToSubstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var test='http://somedomain.com/ijob-css/index.php/search/default/index/area/act?query=&activities_id=13&session_id=14&back=1';
test=test.split('&')[0];

console.log(test);
```

outputs

> http://somedomain.com/ijob-css/index.php/search/default/index/area/act?query=